How to pass syscalls with variable args of different types through ring buffer to kernel?
Different syscalls has different quantity of arguments of different types. How to make system to call all syscalls types through ring buffer. And it should work fast because it is system calls.
I can think of something like this:
typedef struct {
    int syscall_num;
    int param_count;
    size_t param_sizes[MAX_PARAMS];
    void *params[MAX_PARAMS];
} syscall_t;

//Pack the System Call Parameters
void pack_syscall_args(syscall_t *syscall, void *buffer) {
    size_t offset = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < syscall->param_count; i++) {
        memcpy(buffer + offset, syscall->params[i], syscall->param_sizes[i]);
        offset += syscall->param_sizes[i];
    }
}

But wouldn't it be too slow for system calls?
Or I can use va_list args; or void* pointer what would better strategy?
Maybe someone knows how this is made in Linux io_ring using shared memory, if it can be used for all system calls.
